# SQL full text search on multiple columns with AND logic and wildcard

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have 3 searchable columns. When user enters more than 1 word I have to search for a row which has all the words (AND) and it can be matched in any of the 3 columns. All the words should be searched with wildcard (word*). How can I do this in SQL full text search.

I tried with contains function with AND operator. It looks like it searches only on one column.

In a table "Items" I have 2 column Details and Assignee.
[image]

When user search for "doxy vive" I need to search in both the columns with prefix and AND.
This is what I tried and did not work. It works with OR condition.

```
select Details
from [Items]
where CONTAINS((Details,Assignee),'"doxy*" AND "vive*"')
```

This explains how to search on multiple columns but I need to do AND on multiple columns.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#querying-multiple-columns-full-text-search

Comment: Please show sample data, expected results and your attemtp (all as formatted text).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I dont know if its the best solution, but I solved it like this:

```
select Details from [Items] where CONTAINS(*,'"vive*"') AND CONTAINS(*,'"doxy*"')
```